# Node doesn't support import/export even if --experimental-modules is set

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to get Node to handle import/export, but I getting syntax errors in the import statement at `"import $" -> Unexpected identifier`

**Node**:

```
node start.js --experimental-modules
```

**start.js**:

```
(() => {
    import $ from "SCRIPT//CommonImport";
});
```

**commonImport.js**:

```
(() => {
    export var $ = require("jquery");
});
```

**package.json**:

```
{
  "type": "module",
  "name": "lc.assets.hyper",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "brand new UI for LC Assets",
  "main": "start.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Stein Lundbeck",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "jquery": "^3.4.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: The `import` statement must be at the global (module) level; it can't be in a function.

Comment: I moved it but same error

Answer (score 4):

You have to declare all `import`s at the top of the file like this:

```js
import $ from "/my/path"
```

And you can't use `export` statements inside of functions, they have to be declared in the upper scope of your module. And you can't use `require` (CommonJS) if you're using ES6 import/export, but you can use `export ... from ...` construction:

```js
export {default as $} from "jquery"
```

If you want to import modules dynamically you'll have to do it like this:

```js
async function myFunc() {
  const exportedVar = await import('/my/path')
}
```

Note that `import()` returns a `Promise`, i.e. it is async operation, not synchronous as `require`.

Also note, you can't use `export` dynamically like `import()`

Answer (score 0):

Using the esm module did the trick.

**Install**:

```
npm install esm --save-dev
```

**Use**:

```
node -r esm start.js
```

Comment: Adding `esm` might make the code in your example run, but that doesn’t change that it’s invalid syntax. It’s just that `esm` converts it for you. You should still make the corrections proposed by @GProst so that your code runs in Node once `--experimental-modues` is no longer necessary.